# How to echo a `round`ed value in PHP without localisation affecting it?

Tags: php, internationalization

I'm colouring an element on my page with CSS using `style="background:hsl(10, 20.2%, 30.3%)"`.

Unfortunately those 20.2 and 30.3 numbers actually come from variables:

```
return 'hsl('.round($h, 1).', '.round($s, 1).'%, '.round($l, 1).'%)';
```

This is fine if a user's locale is set to English, but if they're (for instance) from France (and have their browser set appropriately) it comes out as `style="background:hsl(10, 20,2%, 30,3%)"`

Which isn't very helpful.

What's the "correct" way to fix this problem?

This works fine, but makes me feel very dirty:

```
return str_replace('|', ',', str_replace(',', '.', 'hsl('.round($h, 1).'| '.round($s, 1).'%| '.round($l, 1).'%)'));
```

Thanks,

Comment: Via the headers passed with the HTTP request, @Andreas.  I assure you this is a PHP question!

Comment: I'm not french but I also have comma as decimal separator, but it looks just as it should on my screen. https://3v4l.org/UDkX4

Comment: @Andreas He might be using `   setlocale() ` function somewhere in his php code and according to that the php thinking his values as money numbers and converting them from decimal to comma but I am not sure OP can give better explanation

Comment: If you have a browser preference for number formatting that's not going to affect these lines of code that I have:

`$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
define('LOCALE', $locale);
putenv('LANG='.LOCALE.'.utf8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, LOCALE.'.utf8');`

Comment: `str_replace()` can take an array of values, you don't need to call it multiple times.

Comment: Worthy note @Qirel, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this is the "best" solution:

```
// this function prevents foreign locales from putting commas in values where
// we want decimals - such as generating HSL numbers for CSS styles

function localeSafeRound(float $value, int $digits): string
{
    return (string) number_format($value, $digits, '.', '');
}

$css = 'hsl('.localeSafeRound($h, 1).', '.localeSafeRound($s, 1).'%, '.localeSafeRound($l, 1).'%)';
```

It does make me worry what other issues lurk in my codebase with regards to this though... and makes me wonder if maybe I should move away from setlocale/gettext to some other i18n strategy.

Thanks to @Technofrood for pointing me in the `number_format` direction.